# Session message is not appearing

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, mailchimp-api-v3.0

For some reason, the session message that the users have subscribed is not appearing.  Below is my code in the controller.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Mailchimp;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('pages.welcome');
    }

    public function postSubscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $listId ='d073cb8994';
        $email = request()->input('email');
        if(Mailchimp::check($listId, $email))
        {
            return "The email {$email} has been registered";
        };

        Mailchimp::subscribe(
            $listId,
            $email,
            [],
            false
        );
        Session::flash('success', 'You have now subscribed');
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
?>
```

I am not sure if it has appeared and I have not made room for it in my blade file (if that makes sense).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thinking might be too easy, but are you checking in the `blade` file if your sesson has data (`success` in this case)?

The code below should work (in combination with your current code within the controller).

Add the following code to your `blade` template:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('success') }}</div>
@endif
```